# No activity found to handle intent action.dial

Tags: android, android-intent, android-permissions, phone-number, phone-call

I'm trying to make my app call a number from an EditText, but I get:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.DIAL dat=Ring Tel nr. 123456789 }
```

I've searched a while for an answer, but most of the answes are permissions and add activity to the Manifest. I've done both, if I'm not doing it wrong. And I'm running it on my phone, not the emulator. I've tried both with and without the intent-filters. Here are the codes: 
Manifest: `<uses-permission android:maxSdkVersion="19" android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>`

```
        <activity
        android:name="nu.sluggo.testapp.annons.Activity2">
        <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Button to make the call (gets phone number from SharedPrefs to a1 below:)

```
        knapp_ring.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            call.setData(Uri.parse("Telnr:" + a1));
            startActivity(call);
        }
    });
```

Comment: solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32264013/11211963
It is suggested to check whether telephony is supported on device.

Comment: 1.This error will be happens when you are using emulator

Answer (score 85, accepted):

`Ring Tel nr. 123456789` is not a valid phone number, and that is what is in your `Intent`. `"Telnr:" + a1` also would not appear to be valid. Use `tel:` followed by the phone number as the value passed to `Uri.parse()`:

```
 Uri.parse("tel:" + a1)
```

Comment: Aah! Thanks! I thought "tel:" could be any string. -That fixed it. Only problem now is that if the first number is a 0, it gets removed automaticly.. But that's another problem, which I'll probably figure out soon. Thanks again!