# How to be listed to manage a phone call, like Skype or Viber

Tags: android

When a user performs a phone call via the dialer or the contacts, I'd like to be listed as one of the apps which can manage it, like it happens for Skype or Viber or other phone apps.

I've tried without success many different solutions, like to add the following intent-filter in a receiver in the manifest file:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_BUTTON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="tel" />
            <data android:scheme="dial" />
        </intent-filter>
```

All the questions about it here on stackoverflow are not helping me; they are vague and they don't work.

EDIT:
tried to put the intent-filter also in the activity manifest tag. Same result. I've also tried with the CALL_PRIVILEGED action, even if it should not be used by 3rd party apps:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20531973/no-activity-found-to-handle-intent-action-dial

Comment: Not a duplicate of that question