# No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.DIAL }

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to open my phone dialer .But it shows error. I have declared permissions for CALL_PHONE on Android Manifest and also declared class in Android Manifest.

```
case R.id.action_call:
Log.d("Action_call","INside Action call");
Intent dialer = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
startActivity(dialer);
return true;
```

Comment: I think you are using a tab with no call support.

Comment: which os version deos your phone have?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need any permissions for `ACTION_DIAL` Intent. So remove `CALL_PHONE` permission from `AndroidManifest.xml`.

You have not pass any number to fire dial Intent.

Use `tel:` followed by the phone number as the value passed to Uri.parse():

Try this code.

```
 String number = "1234567890";
 Uri number = Uri.parse("tel:" + number);
 Intent dial = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
 dial.setData(number);
 startActivity(dial);
```

**EDIT:**

You can first check whether telephony is supported on device

```
private boolean isTelephonyEnabled(){
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    return tm != null && tm.getSimState()==TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY
}
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Still the same problem persists

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(12246): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.DIAL dat=tel:xxxxxxxxxx }

Comment: in which device you are running app?

Comment: Try ACTION_CALL instead of ACTION_DIAL in above code and also add CALL_PHONE permission in manifest then try

Comment: accessing SimState requires networkState permission, is there any other way to check if Telephone is allowed or not. because making a call doesnt require network state and just adding extra permission for accessing Sim state to check if telephony is allowed looks kind of overkill.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Uri` to parse number..

```
Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
call.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+phone));  //String phone
startActivity(call);
```

Answer (score 0):

- Use try/catch.
- Use Uri to parse number.
- Don't need any permissions for ACTION_DIAL intent.

  ```
  try{
      Intent call_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
      call_intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+phone_number));
      startActivity(call_intent);
  }catch(Exception e){
  }
  ```